Trying to render a checkerboard with Bevy
I'm trying to render a checkerboard (or make a grid-based system in general) in Bevy.
I have this component:
#[derive(Debug, Component)]
/// Defines a single grid.
/// As `Cell` is a term used in Rust terminology, Grid is a better way to refer to this.
pub(crate) struct Grid(u8, u8);

impl Grid {
    pub(crate) fn new(x: u8, y: u8) -> Self {
        Self(x, y)
    }

    pub(crate) fn x(&self) -> u8 {
        self.0
    }

    pub(crate) fn y(&self) -> u8 {
        self.1
    }

    pub(crate) fn indices(&self) -> (u8, u8) {
        (self.x(), self.y())
    }
}

And these startup systems:
pub(crate) fn init_grids(mut commands: Commands) {
    debug!("Initializing grids...");

    //| initializing grids up to u8::MAX
    for x in 0..u8::MAX {
        for y in 0..u8::MAX {
            commands.spawn(Grid::new(x, y));
        }
    }
}

pub(crate) fn paint_grids(
    grid_query: Query<&Grid>,
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<ColorMaterial>>,
) {
    debug!("Painting grids...");

    //| iterating over each grid
    for grid in grid_query.iter() {
        //| unpack x and y val of the grid
        let (grid_x, grid_y) = grid.indices();

        //| choose color black or white based on grid x and y value
        let color = if (grid_x + grid_y) % 2 == 0 {
            Color::BLACK
        } else {
            Color::WHITE
        };

        //| define grid's pixel position
        let pos_x = grid_x * GRID_SIZE;
        let pos_y = grid_y * GRID_SIZE;

        //| create a rectangle
        let mesh_handler =
            Mesh2dHandle(meshes.add(Rectangle::new(GRID_SIZE as f32, GRID_SIZE as f32)));

        //| draw the rectangle
        commands.spawn(MaterialMesh2dBundle {
            mesh: mesh_handler,
            material: materials.add(color), //| define its color
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(pos_x as f32, pos_y as f32, 0.0), //| define its pos in the screen
            ..Default::default()
        });
    }
}

...where GRID_SIZE is a u8 constant and its value is 16.
DefaultPlugins and Camera2dBundle are already initialized, but I get a plain gray screen.
Despite initializing camera and default plugins and adding the systems, it renders a blank screen.

I'm kind of new to Bevy (not to Rust), so I was wondering if there's something I'm missing here.
Thanks in advance.

Environment

Bevy 0.13.2
Rust 1.76.0


Update 1
The projects has a CorePlugin where it sets up all the other plugins. Right now, it only has another plugin named GridPlugin.
Some files that might be related:
// main.rs
use bevy::app::App;
use oxidized_pixel_dungeon::core::CorePlugin;

fn main() {
    App::new().add_plugins(CorePlugin).run();
}

// core/mod.rs
use bevy::{
    app::{Plugin, PluginGroup, Startup},
    core_pipeline::core_2d::Camera2dBundle,
    ecs::system::Commands,
    log::LogPlugin,
    utils::tracing::field::debug,
    DefaultPlugins,
};

use crate::grid::GridPlugin;

pub struct CorePlugin;

impl Plugin for CorePlugin {
    fn build(&self, app: &mut bevy::prelude::App) {
        let default_plugins = DefaultPlugins.set(if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
            LogPlugin {
                level: bevy::log::Level::TRACE,
                filter: "info,wgpu_core=warn,wgpu_hal=warn,oxidized_pixel_dungeon=trace".into(),
                ..Default::default()
            }
        } else {
            LogPlugin {
                level: bevy::log::Level::INFO,
                filter: "info,wgpu_core=warn,wgpu_hal=warn".into(),
                ..Default::default()
            }
        });

        app.add_plugins(default_plugins)
            .add_systems(Startup, init_system)
            .add_plugins(GridPlugin);
    }
}

fn init_system(mut commands: Commands) {
    debug("Running CorePlugin::init_system");
    commands.spawn(Camera2dBundle::default());
}

// grid/mod.rs
pub mod components;
pub(crate) mod constants;
mod systems;

use bevy::{
    app::{Plugin, Startup},
    asset::Assets,
    ecs::system::{Commands, ResMut},
    log::debug,
    math::primitives::Rectangle,
    render::{color::Color, mesh::Mesh},
    sprite::{ColorMaterial, MaterialMesh2dBundle, Mesh2dHandle},
    transform::components::Transform,
};

use crate::grid::systems::{init_grids, paint_grids};

pub(super) struct GridPlugin;

impl Plugin for GridPlugin {
    fn build(&self, app: &mut bevy::prelude::App) {
        debug!("Initializing GridPlugin...");
        app.add_systems(Startup, (init_grids, paint_grids));
    }
}


And? What's the question? Does this code fail to compile? With what error? Does it compile but fail to run? With what error? Does it compile and run but fail to produce the expected result? What did you expect and what happened instead?

Sorry, added the explanation.

If you want to render a grid, on a plane, then that can be done with a shader.  Does each square in the grid need to exist separately for some reason?

Yes, I know it's inefficient but I want to do a grid-based game where each grid might have different properties (might contain a wall, ground, trap, enemy, fire etc.). That's why I decided to take this approach. Even though there might be performance optimizations down the road, I'd rather leave it as an afterthought for now.

I think it's the order of system problem, maybe I can query each Grid with MaterialMesh2dBundle and change color every query. I suspect grid_query: Query<&Grid> is returning empty here as the order of system is parallel, thus non-deterministic. Let's see how it goes.

Your problem is the combination of the two systems paint_grid and init_grid.
They both run only once in the Startup schedule, which means for the first frame of the game.
// init_grids
//...
commands.spawn(Grid::new(x,y))
// ...

Issues a command to the world to insert a entity with the Grid component at the end of the frame. However, this means that the entity is only visible starting at frame 2.
Therefore grid_query: Query<&Grid> is empty at frame 1.
Solutions
The easiest solution would be to merge init_grids and pain_grids to a single system. As it stands currently there is no need for two separate systems anyway.
Another approach would be to run paint_grids in the Update schedule instead and query for newly added Grid components.
// GridPlugin
app.add_systems(Startup, init_grids)
.add_systems(Update, paint_grids)

// paint_grids
fn pain_grids(
grid_query: Query<&Grid, Added<Grid>>,
//...
) {
//...
}

This would add the mesh entity whenever a new Grid component was inserted into the world. You might worry that this may be expensive since we query every frame but it actually is really cheap.
I also wouldn't separate visual/mesh and the Grid component into two distinct entities. There is little reason to do so and may make synchronization a bit tedious
